# Flutter - How to get context when not in a class with a build method

Tags: flutter

I'm writing code for a PaginatedDataTable, but I get lost when I try to use showDialog(). 
What I want is when the user presses a row in the DataTable, a dialog box appears with information that row contains.  The problem I'm having, is the context for the Dialog box, because it requires context, and the DataRow class doesn't innately have context.

In order to recognize that a row has been selected, you have to use onSelectChanged() in the DataRow class.  Here, I'm trying to call the dialog box, but I have to use a Global navigator key.

```
class CalendarResultsDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  final List<CalendarResult> _calendarResults;
  CalendarResultsDataSource(this._calendarResults);


  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _calendarResults.length) return null;
    final CalendarResult calendarResult = _calendarResults[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
        index: index,
        selected: calendarResult.selected,
        onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
          print(value);
          print(calendarResult.agency);
          Dialogs.showAuditInfo(
              navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context, calendarResult);  //<-- this feels hacky
        },
        cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: index.isEven
                  ? ColorDefs.colorAlternatingDark
                  : ColorDefs.colorDarkBackground,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text('${calendarResult.getDateFormatted()}',
                        style: ColorDefs.textBodyWhite15)),
              ))), etc. etc.

        ]);
```

in the dataRow class.

So, I created a navigator key in main() like this:

```
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: Scaffold(body: AwesomeAppCodeHere())
    );
  }
}
```

Then, I'm referring to that key in the onSelectChanged() method like this:

```
showDialog<void>(
      context: navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return DialogInnards();
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

But, it feels hacky.  The only other solution I can think of is to pass context to the DataRow class from the PaginatedDataTable widget, but then I'd have to modify the flutter DataRow widget directly.

So, what's the best way to get context in a class without an exposed context?

I did see the 'get' package: might work... https://pub.dev/packages/get but isn't that overkill for something that is straightforward? (but just escaping me?)

Comment: pass `context` inside `return DialogInnards(context);` and make sure your `DialogInnards` class has a `BuildContext` field, and a matching constructor.

Comment: I updated my question.  I can't pass context from the DataRow class, because it's not exposed there.  (and I would have to change the flutter widget to add it)

Comment: if you think `get` package is overkill, i would suggest using global variable. But global variables in general are not a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

As said in the doc `DataTableSource` is long lived object that should be reused across build from the `PaginatedDataTable`, so you should not pass context to the `DataTableSource` object IMO.

I prefer to pass callback that will be called once a row is tapped.

Here a simplified example of what I use in my app :

```
class PlayerDataSource extends DataTableSource {

  /// When no other user is selected, this callback will be called from the onTap event on a Datarow.
  final void Function(Player player)? onTap;

  /// Allow the pagined data table to know if it should show the checkbox
  final void Function(bool displayCheckbox)? onSelect;

  PlayerDataSource({this.onTap, this.onSelect});

  List<Player> displayedPlayers = [];
  int _selectedCount = 0;

  @override
  int get rowCount => displayedPlayers.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= displayedPlayers.length) {
      return null;
    }
    final player = displayedPlayers[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      index: index,
      selected: player.selected,
      onSelectChanged: (isSelected) {
        if (_selectedCount == 0) {
          onTap?.call(player);
          return;
        }
        if (_selectedCount == 1 && isSelected != null && !isSelected) {
          onSelect?.call(false);
        }
        selectOne(player, isSelected ?? false);
      },
      onLongPress: _selectedCount == 0
          ? () {
              onSelect?.call(true);
              selectOne(player, true);
            }
          : null,
      cells: [
        // Wrap Text with builder to access context and get localizations
        DataCell(Builder(builder: (context) {
          final local = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
          return Text(player.hasSub ? local.yes : local.no);
        })),
        DataCell(Text('0')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

PS : If you need context inside a cell, you could wrap you cell child widget (here a `Text` widget) inside a `Builder` widget

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with the same thing, and I've found a workaround.
You can declare a BuildContext attribute in your DataTableSource implementation class.

```dart
    class EventData extends DataTableSource {
      final BuildContext context;
      EventData({required this.context});
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _data = List.generate(
          200,
          (index) => {
                "price": Random().nextInt(1000),
              });
    
      @override
      DataRow? getRow(int index) {
        return DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Center(
            // We can know use the context in this method.
            child: Text("${_data[index]['price']} €",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline6!
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          )),
        ]);
      }
    
      @override
      bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
    
      @override
      int get rowCount => _data.length;
    
      @override
      int get selectedRowCount => 0;
    }
```

This attribute has to be provided by your UI and can now be used in the DataTableSource class's methods.

```dart
class PaginatedExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaginatedExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PaginatedDataTable(
      source: EventData(context: context), //The context can be provided here.
      columns: const [
        DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The drawback of this solution is that the EventData class will be re-instanciated at each UI rebuilds.